# Get value from jQuery editor to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using this [jquery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor.html) to create a wysiwyg text editor,

I created a textarea in PHP where:

```
<textarea name="body" id="body"><?php echo $body?></textarea>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
  $("#body").Editor();
  });
</script>
```

Now i need to get value of this area for send it to SQL

```
if (isset($_POST['add-article'])) {     
  unset($_POST['add-article']);
  $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
  $_POST['username'] = htmlentities($_SESSION['username']);
  $_POST['published'] = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
       
// I need this line
  $_POST['body'] = htmlentities($_POST['body']);
```

When I put text into this editor, it doesn't enter (value) into the textarea.
I have to have value before I press the add-article button, beacuse now it gives me an empty text.

I found something like this

```
function displayText(){
  alert($("#body").Editor("getText"));
}
```

This causes it to return text ( i think only display by JS ) but i completely dont know how to use in my PHP scripts.

Second thing is when i write article and make a mistake something like ( Article title already exist ) ( in one session ) text in textarea stayed, but now doesn`t work it.

I think about if there is an error for example "Title already exist" follows:

```
} else {
    
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];
  $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
  $published = isset($_POST['published']) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

In my honest opinion i need something like:

```
add-article.addEventListener('click', function {
  $body (from PHP) = alert($("#body").Editor("getText"))(from JS); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `$_POST` variables? `$_POST` is used for PHP receiving values from the browser.

Comment: Is the text area in a `<form>` that you submit?

Comment: @Barmar

I assign `$_POST` to variables, beacause i need it for check errors later for example any forbidden words and return they when any errors will occur

Yes 
`<form action="create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
and
`<button type="submit" class="bttn" name="add-article">ADD</button>`

Comment: Then I can't think of a good reason why `$_POST['body']` wouldn't contain the contents of the text area.

Comment: @Barmar It's because of 

`$("#body").Editor();` 

One week ago i used another editor and it worked.

Maybe its something in editor scritp ?

It looks like editor which is not textarea replaced textarea

Answer (score 2):

On the plugin page you referenced, I see this is one of the recommendations. Capture the value you want when the click button is pressed, before the form submits.

Add a script to your form submit to put the texteditor content into this element

```
<form onsubmit='return getItReady()'>
```

Add an element to the form you'll use as a proxy element and keep it hidden, something like

```
 <textarea id='txtEditorContent' name='txtEditorContent' style='visibility:hidden;height:0px' tabindex="-1"></textarea>
```

Then add the script to prepare it

```
<script>
function getItReady() {
 console.log('The content:', $('#body').Editor("getText"));
 $('#txtEditorContent').val($('#body').Editor("getText"));
 return true;
}
</script>
```

Then in your PHP, it will come through as `$_POST['txtEditorContent']`.

Comment: I appreciate the help but it doesn`t work. 
When i press the button PHP check my body value if its empty PHP return error and cleans editor content

Comment: My textarea wasn't closed correctly, I just fixed that, which could have caused the error. Also, make sure that textarea is located in your `<form>` tag. Also, I added a console.log statement to the function. Change `return true` to `return false` to test that console.log - `return false` will force the form NOT to submit so you can test the javascript

Comment: Yes, my textarea is located in `<form>`.

I think that the biggest problem is text input. Your idea didn't work because button add-article send empty `$_POST['body']`.

I added function to button ADD and add hidden textarea.


I need to search other editor which doesn`t replaced a textarea.
Or if i have time, I will poke around in editor.js